# Spring configuration from yaml - combining @ConfigurationEnabled loading for parametrized file name

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration, yaml

I'm having a problem probabably quite unique. I have two applications in the same project, using two different spring configuration files.

When I run them I manually load the context

```
context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("hal.context.xml");
context.registerShutdownHook();
```

and I specify the required spring context file in each of them.

The problems comes from the configuration, because I have two configuration files stored in yaml files.

My best solution would be to use the Spring Boot facility to load the configuration (they have the same structure) in a POJO using

```
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration("configuration")
@ConfigurationProperties
@EnableConfigurationProperties
```

and

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yaml = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
    yaml.setResources(new ClassPathResource("filename"));
    propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setProperties(yaml.getObject());

    return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
}
```

I cannot find a way to load the configuration in a parametrised way... Is there any option combining this and perhaps

```
<bean id="yamlProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlPropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="resources" value="classpath:hal.config.yml"/>
</bean>
```

but instead of using as property placeholder `<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="yamlProperties"/>` to find a way to automatically generate the POJO with the configuration.

Thank you in advance

Luca

Answer (score 0):

You could separate the configuration values by using two different prefixes (one for each config file):

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setPlaceholderPrefix("${app1:");
    propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setPlaceholderSuffix("}");

    YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yaml = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
    yaml.setResources(new ClassPathResource("app1_config_filename"));
    propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setProperties(yaml.getObject());

    return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
}

@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setPlaceholderPrefix("${app2:");
    propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setPlaceholderSuffix("}");

    YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yaml = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
    yaml.setResources(new ClassPathResource("app2_config_filename"));
    propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setProperties(yaml.getObject());

    return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
}
```

Then when injecting configuration values into your beans you can do:

```
@Value("{$app1:myVal}")
String myVal;
```

and

```
@Value("{$app2:myVal}")
String myVal;
```

Into beans from app1 and app2

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. The problem suggest me to split the application into two separate one, but I'm trying to find a workaround. My second option is to inject manually every property into the configuration file (I have two spring context xml files). 
Unfortunately your solution won't work because the Configuration POJO can hold only one configuration (I have two configuration files with the same structure).

I might not have been clear in my explanation, feel free to let me know if you need more infos.

Comment: I would highly recommend splitting the app into two. It will be easier to mantain and configure and you will not run into unexpected bugs from one app generated by the other

Comment: I know, but it's too early at this stage. I still hope in a workaround :-)